# How to combine two tables' data to JSON in Rest Framwork?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My rest framwork serializers is as below:

```
class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addline = serializers.JSONField();
    city = serializers.JSONField();
    unitcode = serializers.JSONField();
    maid = serializers.JSONField();

    class Meta:
        model = address
        fields = ('addline', 'city', 'unitcode', 'maid')
```

I have two models:

```
class address(models.Model):
    addline = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    unitcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    maid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)

class dep(models.Model):
    maid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

This is example of filter:

```
queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__icontains=‘110A Ave’)
```

The Data Current I get is:

```
       [ {
            "addline": "14075 110A Ave",
            "city": "Surrey",
            "unitcode": "U",
            "maid": 113091
        },
        {
            "addline": "14143 110A Ave",
            "city": "Surrey",
            "unitcode": "S",
            "maid": 113104,
      ]
```

But what I want is when the unitcode is "U", there will be a more item: unit, like as below:

```
       [ {
            "addline": "14075 110A Ave",
            "city": "Surrey",
            "unitcode": "U",
            "maid": 113091
        },
        {
            "addline": "14143 110A Ave",
            "city": "Surrey",
            "unitcode": "S",
            "maid": 113104,
            "unit": [ "A-101", "A-102", "A-103", "A-104"]
        }
      ]
```

update2:

Base on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument, my current Models.py is as below:

```
class address(models.Model):
    addline = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    unitcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    maid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)

class dep(models.Model):
    maid = models.ForeignKey(address, related_name='tracks', 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

serializers.py is as below:

```
class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = address
        fields = ('addline', 'city', 'unitcode', 'tracks')
```

But it did not work, is there any problem?

Answer (score 1):

I build my serializers like this, pay atention to **Depth** attributo ate you Meta class, he controle how depth you want to go with your joins... if you set to 1 (is default) he will bring only the objects ids... 2 he will bring the object, but if you have object inside object you should use 3...

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Bar.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('bar',) 
        depth = 2 # this do the magic!
```

**EDIT:** You should use ForeignKeys in your relation... but if you dont want to do that override your class queryset and join the both querysets

Here one example: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/django-rest-framework-override-get-queryset

**EDIT2:** I guess you can configure your models like that, i'll have one istance for **maids** , one for **address** and you can use your dep class to make your relations with it

```
class Address(models.Model):
   ...

class Maid(models.Model):
   ...

class Dep(models.Model):
    maid = models.ForeignKey(Maid, unique)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    ...
```

And your serializer will be like that

```
class DepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    maid = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Maid.objects.all())
    address = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Address.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Dep
        fields = ('__all__') 
        depth = 2 # With 2 will bring full data from Maid and Address Table
```

Comment: Thanks for your warm help. I am confused about foreign key and primary key in Django. I have same column <maid> in two tables, and I want to use this ID to connect among tables. Please see my update in question, if you have time, please you give me more guide, thanks!

Comment: @YuchenHuang what is the relation between `dep` and `address` models that you want to achieve. Is it `one dep to many address OR vice-versa` OR something else?

Comment: in one address, there is unique maid, when the unitcode is "U", there will be a range of units in dep. address and dep is all only one.

Comment: your models is a little bit confuse to me, you trying to setup many deps with maids and address? if is you should put ur foreignkeys at Dep (Maid and Adress) and if is only possible locate 1 maid e only 1 address you should use unique at maid foreignkey

Comment: i'll make another answer cuz they not allow here to ident the code i want to paste

Answer (score 0):

```
class AddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Address
    fields = ['addline', 'city', 'unitcode', 'maid']
```

Now you want to add the details unit, there are multiple.

If the two tables are related via FK, you can lookup the topic Related fields http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

or

You can create a method like this

```
class AddressSerilaizer(ModelSerilizer):
  units = SerilizerMethodField()

  def get_units(self, obj):
    return # your logic here
```

BTW, your formatting is a little off, class name are always CamelCase.

Comment: Thanks for your warm help. I am confused about foreign key and primary key in Django. I have same column <maid> in two tables, and I want to use this ID to connect among tables. Please see my update in question, if you have time, please you give me more guide, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard approach(models.py):

```
 class Address(models.Model):
     addline = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     unitcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     maid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)

     @property
     def unit_json(self):
         dep = Dep.objects.get(maid=self)
         if dep:
            return dep.unit

     def as_json(self):
       return dict(
           addline=self.addline,
           city=self.city,
           unitcode=self.unitcode,
           maid=self.maid,
           unit=self.unit_json,
       )
```

Then,

```
 queryset = address.objects.filter(addline__icontains=‘110A Ave’)
 queryset_json = [ob.as_json() for ob in queryset]
```